# How to define a map in Xcore

Tags: eclipse-emf, emf, xcore

According to the [EMF FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EMF/FAQ), it is possible to create a Map in EMF:

> An EMap is basically a List of java.util.Map$Entry instances.
>   Therefore to create a Map you need to first model your map entry by
>   following these steps:
>
> 1. Create an EClass with the name [Type1]To[Type2]Map where [Type1] represents the key's type and the [Type2] represents the value's type.
> 2. Set the Instance Class Name property of the newly created EClass to java.util.Map$Entry.
> 3. Create an EAttribute or EReference named "key" and set the EDataType or EClass for it.
> 4. Create an EAttribute or EReference called "value" and set the EDataType or EClass for it.
>
> Now, when you create an EReference somewhere that uses this map entry
>   class as its EClass, the EMF code generator will detect this special
>   case and generate a properly typed EMap getter/setter for you instead
>   of a normal EList getter/setter.

Can I use this with [Xcore](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Xcore) models? I am not sure whether step #2 is doable in Xcore or whether it supports maps at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me this works.

`DataPoints.xcore`:

```java
...
class KeyValuePair wraps java.util.Map$Entry {
    String key
    String value
}

class KeyValueList {
    contains KeyValuePair[] entries
}
```

The above results in a `KeyValueListImpl` class with a `getEntries` method that looks like this:

```java
public EMap<String, String> getEntries() {
    if (entries == null) {
        entries = new EcoreEMap<String,String>(DataPointsPackage.Literals.KEY_VALUE_PAIR, KeyValuePairImpl.class, this, DataPointsPackage.KEY_VALUE_LIST__ENTRIES);
    }
    return entries;
}
```